# Regex: How do you get/extract information from an email using regular expressions (in ruby)?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to extract information from an email address like so in ruby:

```
Email: Joe Schmo <joeschmo@abc123.com>
```

to get these three variables:

```
name = ?
email = ?
domain = ?
```

I've tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find how to do it correctly. Here's what I have so far:

```
the_email_line = "Email: Joe Schmo <joeschmo@abc123.com>"

name = (/^Email\: (.+) <(.+)>@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(.+)/).match(the_email_line)[1]
email = (/^Email\: (.+) <(.+)>@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(.+)/).match(the_email_line)[2]
domain = (/^Email\: (.+) <(.+)>@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(.+)/).match(the_email_line)[3]
```

Any idea on how to get those three variables correctly?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that the regex for the email address is incomplete, you should be assigning the result of `.match()` to a temporary variable and indexing that.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio for the tip!

Comment: Using parallel assignment should eliminate the need for a temporary variable altogether (cast match result to an array first).

Comment: There are several questions asking about regular expressions for emails. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses is one of them. They aren't all ruby-related, but at least some of them use a similar regexp syntax. If you're interested in regular expression questions, you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/Email: (.+) <(.+?)@(.+)>/
```

Then grab what you want out of the capturing groups.

Comment: In particular, try `dummy, name, domain, email = (/Email: (.+) <(.+?)@(.+)>/).match(the_email_line).to_a`.  You can throw away `dummy` (just a copy of the matched string).

Comment: Better yet: `name, domain, email = (/Email: (.+) <(.+?)@(.+)>/).match(the_email_line).to_a[1..3]`